# How to get a return value from a jquery widget function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have write a jquery widget with a public function

```
 $.widget("UI.MyWidget", {
        vars: {
            retvalue:0
                  },
        options: {
            Orgintop: 0,
            Orginleft: 0,
            Orginheight: 0,
            Orginwidth: 0
        },
        _create: function () {
            this._renderElement();

        },
        getControlValue: function () {
            this.vars. retvalue=45+5;
            return this.vars. retvalue;
        }
});
```

and I need to call this public function getControlValue from another script. How can I call this and get that return value. I am new in widget. can any one help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are no "public" functions, you have an object literal with a property that is a function, and that object literal is passed directly to a function without a reference, so you can't access that function later

Answer (score 1):

You can set `getControlValue` at `.data()` of `this.element`, return named function from set `.data()` with `this` set to widget which is callable by referencing `.data()` of element where widget is set.

```js
$.widget("UI.MyWidget", {
  vars: {
    retvalue: 0
  },
  options: {
    Orgintop: 0,
    Orginleft: 0,
    Orginheight: 0,
    Orginwidth: 0
  },
  _create: function() {
    this.element.data("_getControlValue", this.getControlValue());
    // this._renderElement();
  },
  getControlValue: function() {
    var fn = function() {
      this.vars.retvalue = 45 + 5;
      return this.vars.retvalue;
    }
    return fn.bind(this)
  }
});

var widget = $("div").MyWidget();
console.log(widget.data()._getControlValue());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: can we get this by without initialize the widget ?

Comment: @Arun _"can we get this by without initialize the widget ?"_ What is purpose of including function within widget pattern if you are trying to use function without initializing widget? You can use a plain object to define functions if expected result is to use the function when object is defined.

Comment: Hi, Actually I need to call this function in  a submit function. I already initialize the widget before that. So how can  I call the function in the submit click function ?

Comment: @Arun _"So how can I call the function in the submit click function ?"_ Have you tried calling the function within `.submit()` event handler?

Comment: No. Actually I am new in widget. Can you give me a example?